# how do i cache password for git on mac

Tags: macos, git

I am following the instructions at https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git. But when I get to the step

```
sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain \
  "$(dirname $(which git))/git-credential-osxkeychain"
# Move the helper to the path where git is installed
# Password: [enter your password]
```

I keep getting errors for `dirname`. `dirname` is my `/User/myname` directory. so I try replacing it with `/User/myname`, then with `/`, then with `.`. Each time it throws a complaint such as

```
-bash: dirname: is a directory
mv: git-credential-osxkeychain: No such file or directory
```

Or in the case of `.`

```
-bash: ????: command not found
mv: git-credential-osxkeychain: No such file or directory
```

But when I go to my `HD` I do see the file `git-credential-osxkeychain` there under path (ie info) `/`

Comment: You should be typing `dirname`, not the actual name of the directory.

Comment: hahaha! No kidding! Thank you so much. And for password, is it my git password or my computer's password? Also will you please post as response so I may mark this thread as answered? Thanks.

Comment: @bdesham Now I am getting the error: `mv: rename git-credential-osxkeychain to /usr/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain: No such file or directory`. And when I do `ls /usr/bin` it is indeed not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to input the command

```
sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain \
    "$(dirname $(which git))/git-credential-osxkeychain"
```

exactly as it is written; don’t replace `dirname` with a directory name. (The point of this command is to get your shell to do that replacement itself.)

The password you’re prompted for is your computer’s password—the use of `sudo` is what’s triggering the password prompt here.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am getting the error: `mv: rename git-credential-osxkeychain to /usr/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain: No such file or directory`. And when I do `ls /usr/bin` it (i.e. `git-credential-osxkeychain`) is indeed not there. (+1)

Comment: If a previous `mv` command worked then the original `git-credential-osxkeychain` file—the one you’re trying to move—is no longer there. Either find where it went in your filesystem or just redownload it.

Comment: If I do `ls` in the home directory it is not there. But if I go to the HD I see it there. So I know it is downloaded to location `/`. Then I do `ls /` and I see it there. So is there a way to modify the command to get it right?

Comment: ok, I got it. I had to do `sudo mv /git-credential-osxkeychain "$(dirname $(which git))/git-credential-osxkeychain"`. Basically, I added the `/`